# Decrypt text that was encrypted with symmetric cipher JAVA

Tags: java

I am trying to decrypt a text file.I have the original text and the encrypted one ,plus the encryption code  itself.I think it is similar to XOR 
cipher but I am not sure.I read about Known-plaintext attack but wasn't able to find good example to try and implement in my task.
I know java is using linear congruential formula and that I can use brute force to find the key for the decryption.
In my code I was trying to play with the seed .I tried to compare to strings each  time after decryption was made but I did not succeed.Any help would be much appreciated.

```
public class test {

    public static int KEY = 0; // enter code here
    public static Random _rand = new Random(KEY);
    private static int counter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        init_seed();
        simple_test0();
        decMSG();
    }

    public static void init_seed() {
        _rand = new Random(KEY);
    }

    public static void simple_test0() { 
        String [] msg = {"Iron Beast"};

        int len = msg.length; 
        String[] msg_enc = new String[len];  
        init_seed();
        for(int i = 0; i < len; i++) { 
            msg_enc[i] = enc(msg[i]); 
        } 
        init_seed(); 
        System.out.println(_rand);
        for(int i=0;i<len;i++) { 
            String se2 = enc(msg_enc[i]);
            System.out.println(i+") orig: "+msg[i]+"\n"+"   enc(orig): "+msg_enc[i]+"\n"+"   enc(enc(orig)): "+se2);
            System.out.println();
        } 
    } 

    public static String enc(String msg) {
        String ans ="";
        for(int i = 0; i < msg.length(); i++) {
            char c = msg.charAt(i);
            int s = c;
            int rd = _rand.nextInt() % (256*256);

            int s2 = s ^ rd;
            char c2 = (char) (s2);
            ans += c2;
        }
        return ans;
    }

    public static void decMSG() throws Exception {

        boolean ans = false;
        String file_name = "msg";

        String msg = "first text line";

        FileReader fr = new FileReader(file_name);
        BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(fr); 
        String s = is.readLine();
        int key = 0;
        while(ans == false ) {
            KEY =key;
            s = enc(s);
            if(msg.equals(s)) {
                System.out.println(s + "\t" + KEY);
                ans = true;
                counter++;
            }
            _rand = new Random(key);
            System.out.println( KEY);
            if(key > 10000000) {    
                key=0;  
            }
            key++;
        }
        System.out.println(counter);
        is.close();
        fr.close(); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Care to explain it a bit? Example text & it's encrypted string?

Comment: Found a solution,had to use the random object instense to encrypt and once more to decrypt.Using brute force and a while loop I found the seed to the given algorithm. It was an encrypted text file.

Comment: When you find a solution yourself, you should post it as an answer for your own question and mark it as accepted. Could be helpful to other people as well.